# Align image links to center

Tags: html, css

I have some image link in a div and want to align them in the center of the div:

```
<div id="tecnologies">
    <div id="footerpics">
        <a href=""><img src="pics/pythonsmall.png" alt=""></a>
        <a href="‎"><img src="pics/djanogsmall.png" alt=""></a>
        <a href=""><img src="pics/bluefishsmall.png" alt=""></a>
        <a href=""><img src="pics/gimpsmall.png" alt=""></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
footer {
    width: 977px;
    background-color: #BFBFBF;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
}

#tecnologies {
    margin: 0 auto;
    direction: ltr;
    font-size: 12px;
}

#tecnologies a {
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#footerpics {
    width: auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

The code is not working.
I tried different methods, but had no success.
How should I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#footerpics { text-align:center; }
```

Answer (score 0):

In order for

```
margin: 0 auto;
```

to work it needs at least 2 properties which is:

```
display:block;
width: ...px;
```

I needs to be a block with a specified width in order for `margin: 0 auto;` to work. Whether it is the proper approach i leave for you to decide.